# Get inactive mailboxes with their primary SMTP address and last logon information

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange, exchange-server

I want to get list of all inactive mailboxes with their primary SMTP address and last logon information.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select DisplayName, LastLoggedOnUserAccount, LastLogonTime
```

This command returns all inactive mailboxes with their display name but problem is that I want to get this list with PrimarySMTPAddress of mailbox because there is a possibility that multiple accounts can have same display name. Is there a way to get it with PrimarySMTPAddress?

Answer (score 1):

The primary SMTP address for an Exchange mailbox is found in its 'ProxyAddresses' attribute. This is a multi-value attribute, and Exchange denotes the primary by using an all-caps 'SMTP:' prefix for the address. Non-primary SMTP addresses will use a lowercase 'smtp:' prefix.

Here's an example of how to query your primary SMTP  address:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity "Muhammad Arsalan Altaf" -Properties ProxyAddresses | select -ExpandProperty ProxyAddresses | ? {$_ -clike "SMTP:*"}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want to get their last logon detail. Get-MailboxStatistics returns logon details with many other details but it gives us display name not primary SMTP address. I'm trying to find such a way that it also returns me primary SMTP address with these statistics by running just one script.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
# actually Exchange management shell 
$results = foreach ($mailboxdata in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)) {
$stats =  Get-MailboxStatistics -identity $mailbox  ;
$mailboxdata | add-member NoteProperty -name LastLoggedOnUserAccount -value  $stats.LastLoggedOnUserAccount 
$mailboxdata | add-member NoteProperty -name LastLogonTime  -value  $stats.LastLogonTime}
$results
```

Or just use https://github.com/cunninghamp/Get-MailboxReport.ps1 by Paul Cunningham former owenr of https://practical365.com

Answer (score 0):

What the version of your exchange server? 
If your exchange server is on premise, I found a similar [scripts](http://blog.jonsson.it/?p=597) for your reference.

If your exchange server is online, you could Go to https://protection.office.com and sign in using the credentials for an administrator account in your Office 365 organization, Click Information governance > Retention, On the Retention page, click MoreNavigation Bar ellipses, and then click Inactive mailboxes.
For more details: [View a list of inactive mailboxes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-and-manage-inactive-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide#view-a-list-of-inactive-mailboxes)

Comment: Server version is Exchange 2019. I want to get these information using code not using UI.

Comment: You could seek for a powershell expert, who will provide the most accurate advice:)